# ngModel not completely refreshing the view when array.splice() called on the binded object

Tags: angular, ngmodel

I am new to Angular and having an issue where my view is not updating properly after I add a new item to an array.  See below for screenshot and relevant code. Any help would be much appreciated!

I have tried re-creating the array (i.e. result =[... result]) to try and force change detection but it did not work. It seems like the delete portion of the .splice() is being detected but not the part where the element gets added back in at the same index.

[image]

**recipeView.component.html**

```
     <!--Recipe display view-->
  <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th style="width:7%">Recipe Name</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Ingredients</th>
        <th>Instructions</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let item of getItems('recipe'); let even = even; let odd=odd">
      <tr *ngIf="( (selectedCategory==undefined) || selectedCategory==(item.category.id)) || (selectedCategory==0) ||( (item.name | lowercase).startsWith((recipeName | lowercase) ) && recipeName !='' )"
          [ngClass]="{ odd: odd, even: even }">
        <td style="vertical-align:middle">{{item.name}}</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle">{{item.category.name}}</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle"><div style="float:left" *ngFor="let ing of item.ingredients"> {{ing.name}}, </div></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle">{{item.instructions}}</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-5 mr-2" [routerLink]="['/addEditRecipe', 'edit', item.id]" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalAddEditRecipe">Edit</button></td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>

  <!-- Modal - Edit or add new recipe -->

  <div class="modal fade modal-dialog" id="ModalAddEditRecipe" *ngIf="operation =='addEditRecipe' " name="ModalAddEditRecipeName" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalAddEditRecipeLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalAddEditRecipeLabel">{{mode == 'edit' ? 'Edit' : 'Create New'}} Recipe</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Recipe Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="inputAddModRecipeName" #inputAddModRecipeName
                   [(ngModel)]="ModNewRecipe.name" required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Category</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="inputAddModCategory" #inputAddModCategory
                   [(ngModel)]="ModNewRecipe.category.name" required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Instructions</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="inputAddModInstructions" #inputAddModInstructions
                   [(ngModel)]="ModNewRecipe.instructions" required />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>ID</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="inputAddModID" #inputAddModInstructions
                   [(ngModel)]="ModNewRecipe.id" required />
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" [routerLink]="['/recipes']" >Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" [routerLink]="['/recipes']" (click)="saveChanges(ModNewRecipe, 'recipe')">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**recipeview.Component**

```
    import { Component, Inject, DoCheck, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { ModelRepo } from "../model/repository.model";
import { Category } from "../model/category.model";
import { Recipe } from "../model/recipe.model";
import { Ingredient } from "../model/ingredient.model";
import { RecipeBook } from "../model/recipeBook.model";



//import { MODES, SharedState, SHARED_STATE } from "./sharedState.model";
//import { Observer} from "rxjs"


@Component(



  {
    selector: "recipeView",
    templateUrl: "recipeView.component.html"
  }

)


export class recipeViewComponent {
  ModNewCategory = new Category();
  ModNewRecipe = new Recipe();
  ModNewIngredient = new Ingredient();
  ModNewRecipeBook = new RecipeBook();
  selectedCategory;
  recipeName;
  testvar = "adasdasdasd";
 //  testObj = new Recipe(999, "test recipe 1", new Category(0, "test cat 1 updated again twice!!!"), new Array<Ingredient>(new Ingredient(0, "test ing")), "test instructions");
  
  id;
  mode;
  operation;
  defaultObject = new Object();
  
  constructor(public dataRepo: ModelRepo, activeRoute: ActivatedRoute, public router: Router)  {
  

    activeRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
   
      this.id = params["id"];
      this.mode = params["mode"];
      this.operation = params["operation"]
      if (this.operation != null && this.mode != null)
      {
        this.modifyItem(this.id, this.operation);
       }
      
    }
   )
  }
 

  modifyItem(key: number, operation: string) {

    switch (operation) {
   /*   case "category":
        Object.assign(this.ModNewCategory, this.dataRepo.getItem(key, type) );
        if (this.ModNewCategory.id != undefined) {return true;}
        else { return false;} */
     

      case "addEditRecipe":
        
            Object.assign(this.ModNewRecipe, this.dataRepo.getItem(key, 'recipe'));
    
            if (this.ModNewRecipe.id == undefined)
            {
              this.ModNewRecipe = new Recipe(null, "Enter new name ", new Category(null, " Enter new Category "), new Array<Ingredient>(new Ingredient(null, " ")), " ");          
            }
              return this.ModNewRecipe;
    
 
      /*
      case "ingredient":
        Object.assign(this.ModNewIngredient, this.dataRepo.getItem(key, type) );
        if (this.ModNewIngredient.id != undefined) { return true; }
        else { return false; }
  
      case "recipeBook":
        Object.assign(this.ModNewRecipeBook, this.dataRepo.getItem(key, type));
        if (this.ModNewRecipeBook.id != undefined) { return true; }
        else { return false; }
        */
    }  
  }

  getItems(type: string) {
    return this.dataRepo.getItems(type);
  }
  deleteItem(item: any, type:string): any {
    return this.dataRepo.deleteItem(item, type)

  }

  onSelectedCategoryChange(selectedOption) {
    this.selectedCategory = selectedOption;
    
  }

  InitalizeItemReferences() {

    this.ModNewCategory = new Category();
    this.ModNewRecipe = new Recipe();
    this.ModNewIngredient = new Ingredient();
    this.ModNewRecipeBook = new RecipeBook();
   
  }

  saveChanges(item: any, type: string) {
    this.dataRepo.saveItem(item, type)

    
  }




}
```

**repository.model.ts**

```
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Category } from "./category.model";
import { Ingredient } from "./ingredient.model";
import { Recipe } from "./recipe.model"
import { RecipeBook } from "./recipeBook.model"
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { RestDataSource } from "./rest.datasource";


@Injectable()
export class ModelRepo
{
  public dataTypes: Array<any>;
  public categories: Array<Category> = new Array<Category>();
  public ingredients: Array<Ingredient> = new Array<Ingredient>();
  public recipes: Array<Recipe> = new Array<Recipe>();
  public recipeBook: Array<RecipeBook> = new Array<RecipeBook>();
  public locator = (i: any, id: number) => i.id == id;

  constructor(private dataSource: RestDataSource) {
  
    this.dataTypes = new Array<any>()
      this.dataTypes = dataSource.returnAllDataTypes(); //get all data types needed for the component

    for (let i = 0; i < this.dataTypes.length; i++)
    { 
      
      this.dataSource.getItems<Category>("Category").subscribe(data => { this.categories = data; })
      this.dataSource.getItems<Ingredient>("Ingredient").subscribe(data => { this.ingredients = data; })
      this.dataSource.getItems<Recipe>("Recipe").subscribe(data => { this.recipes = data; })
     // this.dataSource.getItems<RecipeBook>("RecipeBook").subscribe(data => { this.recipeBook = data; })
      

    }
    


  }

  getDataTypes() {
    return this.dataTypes;
  }
  getItems(type: string): Array<any>
  {
  
    var result = new Array<any>();
    switch (type.toLocaleLowerCase())
    {
      case "category":
        result = this.categories;
        break;
      case "ingredient":
        result = this.ingredients;
        break;
      case "recipe":
        result = this.recipes;
        break;
      
    }

    return result;
  }

  

  getItem(id: number, type:string): any
  {

    var result: any;
    result = this.getItems(type);
    return result.find(i => this.locator(i, id));
  }

  getNextItemId(id: number, type:string): number {


    var result: Array<any>;
    result = this.getItems(type);

    let index = result.findIndex(i => this.locator(i, id));
    if (index > -1) {
      return result[result.length > index + 2
        ? index + 1 : 0].id;
    } else {
      return id || 0;
    }
  }

  getPreviousItemId(id: number, type: string): number{

    var result: any;
    result = this.getItems(type);

    let index = result.findIndex(i => this.locator(i, id));
    if (index > -1) {
      return result[result > 0
        ? index - 1 : result.length - 1].id;
    } else {
      return id || 0;
    }
  } 


  saveItem(item: any, type: string)
  {
    
    var result: any;
   result = this.getItems(type);
  

    if (item.id == 0 || item.id == null) {
      this.dataSource.saveItem(item).subscribe(i => result.push(i));
    

    }
    else
    {
      this.dataSource.updateItem(item, item.id).subscribe(i => {
        let index = result.findIndex(i => this.locator(i, i.id));
        if (index > -1) {    
         result.splice(index, 1);

         
        }

      })
        ;

    }
  }

  deleteItem(item: any, type: string) {

    var result: any;
    result = this.getItems(type);


    this.dataSource.deleteItem(item, item.id).subscribe(() => {
      let index = result.findIndex(i => this.locator(i, item.id));
      if (index > -1) {
        result.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
  }


}

**rest.dataSource.ts**

    import { Injectable, Inject, InjectionToken } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { Category } from "./category.model";
import { Ingredient } from "./ingredient.model";
import { Recipe } from "./recipe.model"
import { catchError, delay } from "rxjs/operators";
import { RecipeBook } from "./recipeBook.model";

export const REST_URL = new InjectionToken("rest_url");

@Injectable()
export class RestDataSource {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient,
        @Inject(REST_URL) private url: string) { }

    getItems<T>(endpointPrefix: string): Observable<T[]> {
      //    return this.sendRequest<Product[]>("GET", this.url);
     
      return this.http.jsonp<T[]>(this.url + endpointPrefix, "callback");
      
    }

    saveItem<T>(item: T): Observable<T> {
        return this.sendRequest<T>("POST", this.url + (item.constructor.name).toString(), item);
    }

    updateItem<T>(item: T, id:number): Observable<T> {   
      
     /* return this.sendRequest<T>("PUT",
        `${this.url + (item.constructor.name).toString()}/${id}`, item); */
      return this.sendRequest<T>("PUT",
        this.url + (item.constructor.name).toString() + "/" + id, item);
    }

  deleteItem<T>(item: T, id: number): Observable<T> {

    return this.sendRequest<T>("DELETE", `${this.url + (item.constructor.name).toString()}/${id}`);
      
    }

    private sendRequest<T>(verb: string, url: string, body?: any)
        : Observable<T> {

        let myHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        myHeaders = myHeaders.set("Access-Key", "<secret>");
        myHeaders = myHeaders.set("Application-Names", ["Rapid Recipes", "MSsanto"]);

        return this.http.request<T>(verb, url, {body: body,headers: myHeaders})   
          .pipe(catchError((error: Response) => throwError(`Network Error: ${error.statusText} (${error.status})`)));
    }

  returnAllDataTypes(): Array<any> {
    var types = new Array<any>(Ingredient, Category, Recipe, RecipeBook);
    return types;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After update api, find the index of item in list and assign the response to that index.

this.dataSource.updateItem(item, item.id).subscribe(i => { let index = result.findIndex(i => this.locator(i, i.id)); if (index > -1) { result[index] = i; }

And at the save function end, assign this new result to this.recipes variable.

---

Comment: Actually, it looks like this did not fix the issue. If I edit the first row, it updates correctly but any row other than the first gives the same behavior.  Strange...